# Change default driver of network printer

Tags: printing

In Ubuntu 12.04, how do I set the driver for a network printer?

It used to be all in the **wizard** provided by `system-config-printer`, but now of course the system itself decides which driver to pick and I really need a **different** one than the **default** driver.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open System Settings, and click on Printers.  Once the window opens, right click on the printer that you want to change its driver, and choose Properties.

[image]

When the properties windows opens, click on Change to the right of Make and Model under Settings.

[image]

Once that window opens, choose driver source, and click on Forward.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just don't get why Ubuntu developers loooove to move things around every few months. It's extremely frustrating to have to search for settings in new places all the time.