# Does ubuntu support HP 1320 printer?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I have an older HP1320 laser printer and had a difficult time getting the drivers to work with my windows computer.

Does Ubuntu come with this driver already built in or will I have to go through the whole process again if I use it??

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu has an older version of hplip drivers, but better to download newer version if newer printer or even if older it may have bug fixes.

HP's newest On this website you can download the HPLIP software which supports 2,211 HP printers on nearly any Linux distribution available today.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Ubuntu's older version

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
gksudo hp-setup
```

new version

```
hp-upgrade
```

I also get no system tray error but have ignored them without issue.

No system tray error:
open up the "startup applications" editor from the admin menu.
add a new program, for the command put:

sleep 10;/usr/bin/hp-systray

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's supported (I have two in my work). But if you use any other driver (yes, I tested Postscript and hpcups from latest hplip version) and then you print anything to the printer... the printer won't stop printing copies. Infinite copies bug!?

So to fix this you need use the driver **Foomatic/pxlmono** or **hpijs** (recommend because it have more fast processing then Foomatic/pxlmono). Follow this steps:

1. Choose and install the driver:

   **hpijs (recommended)**

   > sudo apt-get install printer-driver-hpijs

   **Foomatic/pxlmono**

   Normally you really this drive installed in Ubuntu, but if not:

   > apt-get install foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
2. Install the printer:

   Now install normally the printer from `system-config-printer` (skip if you really do that).
3. Change the default printer driver:

   Then change the driver to **HP Laserjet 1320 hpijs, 3.13.9** or **HP Laserjet 1320 Foomatic/pxlmono** [using this steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/306787/139248).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this printer so I can't be sure at 100%.

I can see that the drivers began to exists for Linux in 2006 (an old thread can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=235104) - do not apply this solution witch is quite old).

The HP website reports linux drivers for Linux.

And finally the [Openprinting page](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-LaserJet_1320) reports it to function correctly with only one advise.

Ubuntu have an out of the box automatic system for adding printers : you should be able to add it on a recent ubuntu easily.

If you are unsure you can try to add it with the live cd part of the ubuntu cd.